# Firewall denies sshd-keygen-wrapper despite configuration

Tags: ssh, firewall

After upgrading to Lion, I cannot connect via SSH.  I get a timeout:

```
$ ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 not.my.actual.hostname
ssh: connect to host not.my.actual.hostname port 22: Operation timed out
```

In `/var/log/appfirewall.log` I get this:

```
Firewall[541]: Deny sshd-keygen-wrapper connecting from 192.168.1.1:49380 to port 22 proto=6
```

I have specifically added `sshd-keygen-wrapper` to my firewall rules and set it to "Allow incoming connections", but I still get the same message in the firewall log.

If I disable the firewall, I can connect without issue, but I'd rather not disable it completely.  What am I missing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem and this is how I fixed it --

1. Delete sshd-keygen-wrapper from firewall list
2. Click + to add it back
3. In the Open dialog press <kbd>Cmd-Shift-G</kbd> and specify `/usr/libexec`
4. select `sshd-keygen-wrapper`

Explicitly adding it in this way worked for me.  Good luck!

After step 4. you have to reboot. Or just restart the firewall by disabling and enabling the firewall in the system settings. Without the restart the new configuration will not be activated.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I already tried that.